# Touch ID on success set a variable

Tags: swift2, touch-id

I am trying to return true or false based on the success/failure of touch id. But by the time the success if condition gets called, the function exits with a false value. I am new to iOS development. I believe I am supposed to use some sort of completion handler, but I dont understand how to, in this specific case.

```
func authenticateUser(reasonString: String) -> Bool {
    // Get the local authentication context.
    let context = LAContext()

    // Declare a NSError variable.
    var error: NSError?

    // Current authorization status of user
    var isAuthorized = false

    // Check if the device can evaluate the policy.
    if context.canEvaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: &error) {
        [context .evaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: reasonString, reply: { (success: Bool, evalPolicyError: NSError?) -> Void in

            if success {
                isAuthorized = true
            }
            else{
                // If authentication failed then show a message to the console with a short description.
                // In case that the error is a user fallback, then show the password alert view.
                print(evalPolicyError?.localizedDescription)

                switch evalPolicyError!.code {

                case LAError.SystemCancel.rawValue:
                    print("Authentication was cancelled by the system")

                case LAError.UserCancel.rawValue:
                    print("Authentication was cancelled by the user")

                case LAError.UserFallback.rawValue:
                    print("User selected to enter custom password")

                default:
                    print("Authentication failed")

                }
            }

        })]
    }
    else{
        // If the security policy cannot be evaluated then show a short message depending on the error.
        switch error!.code{

        case LAError.TouchIDNotEnrolled.rawValue:
            print("TouchID is not enrolled")

        case LAError.PasscodeNotSet.rawValue:
            print("A passcode has not been set")

        default:
            // The LAError.TouchIDNotAvailable case.
            print("TouchID not available")
        }

        // Optionally the error description can be displayed on the console.
        print(error?.localizedDescription)

    }
return isAuthorized
}
```

This function returns false, even before the touchID part is executed. Can somebody please guide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function authenticateUser will always return false as you are return isAuthorized value which set ti false. 
context.canEvaluatePolicy and context.evaluatePolicy are still executing and value is not change for isAuthorized.

Actual Flow is somewhat like this:

Set isAuthorized== false

{call context.canEvaluatePolicy --> Still Executing
    call context.evaluatePolicy --> on Success of context.canEvaluatePolicy}

Return isAuthorized = False --> context.canEvaluatePolicy and context.evaluatePolicy still executing.

Execution flow complete method execution even if the Block Methods are executing.

My Suggestion is to remove return isAuthorized from the end of function and implement success and failure block.